Terraform not detecting the right project when modifying Org Policy
Using Terraform in my local terminal, I've been trying to disable the Disable Service Account Key Creation policy for a specific project and stop it from inheriting the policy from the parent organization.
# Disable the Disable Service Account Key Creation policy for the project
resource "google_org_policy_policy" "disableServiceAccountKeyCreation" {
  name   = "projects/${var.project_id}/policies/iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation"
  parent = "projects/${var.project_id}"

  spec {
    inherit_from_parent = false
    rules {
      enforce = "FALSE"
      }
    }
}

However I keep running into this error:
Error: Error creating Policy: failed to create a diff: failed to retrieve Policy resource: googleapi: Error 403: Your application is authenticating by using local Application Default Credentials. The orgpolicy.googleapis.com API requires a quota project, which is not set by default. To learn how to set your quota project, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/adc-troubleshooting/user-creds .
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "consumer": "projects/7640********",
│       "service": "orgpolicy.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
│   }
│ ]


The thing is:

I did use gcloud auth application-default login to authenticate.
I did set the quota project, despite it already being set.
The Org Policy API is already enabled on this project.

What I noticed is that the project number from projects/7640******** does not match my project number. I also noticed that it's pulling that number from the first portions of the client_id in the application_default_credentials.json file.
How do I fix this? Did I stumble into a bug? Seems like someone from Google reported the same issue back in Feb but no response on that thread.

Posting my answer in part as a comment because Stackoverflow blocked me from being able to post for absolutely no reason.
PART 1:
I believe this turned out to be a bug, here's the GitHub issue I created for it (a thumbs up increases visibility for the product team).

PART 2:
In the meantime, I found a workaround where adding billing_project and user_project_override = true to the providers.tf file helped override the problem happening with the underlying API call.
provider "google" {
  project               = var.project_id
  billing_project       = var.project_id
  region                = var.region
  zone                  = var.zone
  user_project_override = true
}


PART 3: The same can be done by defining the following environment variables in your shell.
export USER_PROJECT_OVERRIDE=true # force resources to use a billing project / export GOOGLE_BILLING_PROJECT=your-quota-project # override the billing project for all resources
